# How to use UIScrollViewDelegate methods on a tableView added to a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

how could we use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods on a tableView that is added to a `UIViewController`? It works fine when I subclass the `UITableViewController`, but in my case, the tableView is added inside a `UIViewController`. The delegate and datasource are linked to `self`, I added UIScrollViewDelegate as a protocol, but the delegate methods are not recognized by the viewController.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewDelegate inherits from UIScrollViewDelegate.
If you determine that object is delegate of table view, it would be also a delegate of scrollView.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have my Xcode bugging. The methods are not autocompleted but they are accepted if I write the whole method.

Comment: @Paul it is normal work for xCode - not to show all inheritance tree methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get this done in two steps:

**ViewController.h**

Your `UIViewController` must implement both the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UIScrollViewDelegate`. If you are working with interface builder, you will also have an `IBOutlet` for the `UITableView`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

**ViewController.m**

In your implementation code, you have to specify that `ViewController` is the `tableview`'s delegate. You also need to implement one of `UIScrollView`'s delegate methods to be notified of the scroll:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"Scrollview did scroll");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually have my Xcode bugging. The methods are not autocompleted but they are accepted if I write the whole method.

Comment: Was my answer helpful then?

Comment: Thanks Dennis for the support, but I already had this done. When you first write the letters, xcode gives you what is available, and in my case xcode was bugging. So I thought the methods were not available.